# Error Converting Curl Request to Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

I am trying to translate a curl request to ruby. I don't understand why this works:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}' https://xxxxxxxx.ws/authenticate
```

while this doesn't:

```
uri = URI('https://xxxxxxxx.ws/authenticate')

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req.set_form_data(username: 'foo', password: 'bar')

res = https.request(req)
```

The response I get is:

```
(byebug) res
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
(byebug) res.body
"{\"error\":\"username needed\"}"
```

Is there any way to inspect what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: your ruby is sending a plain html form-type submission, while curl is sending json. they're two totally different data formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_form_data` will encode the request payload as `www-form-encoded`. You need to simply assign the body directly.

```
uri = URI('https://xxxxxxxx.ws/authenticate')

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req.body = { username: 'foo', password: 'bar' }.to_json

res = https.request(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send `username` and `password` as form-encoded parameters (`set_form_data`) when the `curl` command is sending them as json. Try setting the content body of the request to the json shown in the command.